In Excel vb.net sheetchange event, how can i differentiate between a cell edit and a cell deletion
In an Excel vb.net vsto add-in, editing the contents of a cell, say A1, triggers the sheetchange event.  Deletion of cell A1 (not deletion of its contents but deletion of the cell) also triggers the sheetchange.  In both cases, Target is A1.  How can I differentiate between these two events?
